# ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: windows, cmake, ninja

I tried compiling aseprite 1.3 beta6
and after complete successful cmake command
I excecute ninja aseprite command
and that's what happend :

```
[1042/1544] Building RC object src\CMakeFiles\aseprite.dir\main\resources_win32.rc.res
FAILED: src/CMakeFiles/aseprite.dir/main/resources_win32.rc.res
"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmcldeps.exe" RC C:\aseprite\src\main\resources_win32.rc src\CMakeFiles\aseprite.dir\main\resources_win32.rc.res.d src\CMakeFiles\aseprite.dir\main\resources_win32.rc.res "Note: including file: " "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe -DCMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -DCURL_STATICLIB -DENABLE_DATA_RECOVERY -DENABLE_NEWS -DENABLE_SAVE -DENABLE_SCRIPTING -DENABLE_UI -DENABLE_UPDATER -DGR_GL_FUNCTION_TYPE=__stdcall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLAF_SKIA -DLAF_WINDOWS -DLAF_WITH_REGION -DLUA_FLOORN2I=1 -DNDEBUG -DPNG_NO_MMX_CODE -DSK_ALLOW_STATIC_GLOBAL_INITIALIZERS=1 -DSK_BUILD_FOR_WIN32 -DSK_FORCE_DISTANCE_FIELD_TEXT=0 -DSK_GAMMA_APPLY_TO_A8 -DSK_GAMMA_SRGB -DSK_INTERNAL -DSK_SCALAR_TO_FLOAT_EXCLUDED -DSK_SUPPORT_GPU=0 -DSK_SUPPORT_OPENCL=0 -DTIXML_USE_STL -DUNICODE -DWINVER=0x0A00 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -I C:\aseprite\third_party\zlib -I C:\aseprite\build\third_party\zlib -I C:\aseprite\third_party\libpng -I C:\aseprite\build\third_party\libpng -I C:\aseprite\third_party\libwebp\src -I C:\aseprite\third_party\tinyxml -I C:\aseprite\third_party\pixman\pixman -I C:\aseprite\build -I C:\aseprite\third_party\freetype2\include -I C:\aseprite\third_party\harfbuzz\src -I C:\aseprite\third_party\giflib -I C:\aseprite\third_party\jpeg -I C:\aseprite\third_party\curl\include -I C:\aseprite\third_party\simpleini -I C:\aseprite\src -I C:\aseprite -I C:\aseprite\src\observable -I C:\aseprite\build\src\app -I C:\aseprite\laf -I C:\aseprite\build\laf -I C:\aseprite\laf\third_party\stringencoders\src -I C:\deps\skia -I C:\deps\skia\include\config -I C:\deps\skia\include\core -I C:\deps\skia\include\utils -I C:\deps\skia\include\codec -I C:\deps\skia\include\gpu -I C:\deps\skia\src\gpu -I C:\deps\skia\include\third_party\skcms -I C:\deps\skia\third_party\externals\angle2\include -I C:\aseprite\third_party\cityhash\src -I C:\aseprite\third_party\fmt\include -I C:\aseprite\build\third_party\freetype2\include -I C:\aseprite\third_party\cmark\src -I C:\aseprite\build\third_party\cmark\src -I C:\aseprite\third_party\giflib\lib -I C:\aseprite\third_party\json11 -I C:\aseprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive -I C:\aseprite\third_party\tinyexpr -I C:\aseprite\third_party\lua -DWIN32   -wd4267 -wd4244 /fo src\CMakeFiles\aseprite.dir\main\resources_win32.rc.res C:\aseprite\src\main\resources_win32.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


C:\aseprite\src\main\resources_win32.rc(6) : error RC2237 : numeric value expected at beta6
[1047/1544] Building CXX object src\CMakeFiles\aseprite.dir\main\main.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have:

- Aseprite version 1.3 beta6
- Windows 10 x64
- Cmake 3.18.1.0 x64 with ninja
- skia x64 compiled version
- visual studio 2019 community
- windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK

Comment: What does line 6 of C:\aseprite\src\main\resources_win32.rc contain?

Comment: do you mean this line : FILEVERSION 1,3,0,1.3-beta6-dev ??

Comment: Exactly. The RC file does expect a numerical value on the last position. So replacing the string `1.3-beta6-dev` simply by `0` should be enough to make the build pass. An please file a bug report at https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite repository.

Comment: There has been already filed an issue on the repo https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/2916